# Calling special numbers from iOS app using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I would like to be able to call special numbers using swift to check the current balance or to know the status about some services. I tried the following code but it did not work

```
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"tel://*120#")!;
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone app supports most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone app does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html